# Split Java String with multiple occurence of special character

Tags: java, string

I would like to do the following in Java, and I can't figure out how.

Suppose I have this variable:

```
String text = "test1;test2;test3;test4;";
```

I would like to create a variable `splitText` that has the following :

```
splitText[0] = test1
splitText[1] = test2
splitText[2] = test3
splitText[3] = test4
```

If I use the split method given in Java, I obtain:

```
splitText[0] = test1
splitText[1] = test2;test3;test4
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: What's you `delimiter`

Answer (score 4):

I disagree that split doesn't work:

```
String text = "test1;test2;test3;test4;";
String[] splitText = text.split(";");

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitText));
```

outputs

```
[test1, test2, test3, test4]
```

You probably used `split(2)` which tells Java to split the string into at most 2 parts.

Comment: Well I was doing it, it should come from another problem then... Thanks I will check...

Answer (score 1):

```
String [] arr = text.split(";");
```

arr contains all elements in array form.